# Magento 2.4.6 - How we can add quantity_and_stock_status in layered navigation Graphql?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, graphql, magento2.4.6, magento-graphql

I want to add an "out of stock exclude" filter in Layered Navigation using GraphQl.

I have enabled "Display out of stock" in the admin configuration. And also change the quantity_and_stock_status attribute "Use in layered navigation" to "Filterable (with results)".

Does anyone have an idea to display the out-of-stock filter in layered GraphQl?

Sample query:

```
{
    products(filter: {category_id:{eq: "4"}}) {
        total_count
        aggregations{
            attribute_code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution for the same, please share